# How to handle multiple image upload one by one in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

we have an html form with `<input type="file" name="u_file" class="u_class" id="u_id">`. When user upload an image then it will show in the below div before submitting the form .

```
<div class="preview-div">


</div>.
```

That is when user upload an image then that time we append image to the div by jquery .

```
$("#u_id").change(function(event){

  $(".preview-div").append(' <img style="" class="img-class"  src="'+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])+'">');
  etc.....

});
```

when submit form then  it will check

```
if($_FILES['u_file']['name'] !=""){

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['user_file'];
$image_name=$_FILES['u_file']['name'];

move_imageto_dir();
etc....

}
```

here `move_imageto_dir();` is the custom function we written .

But the problem is that it will only checking and moving the last image . How to solve this ?.

That is ($_FILES['u_file'] only contain the latest upload image . What we need to do ?We can't use `<input type='file'  multiple>`

Thank you .

Comment: so you are uploading multiple image or single image and also please upload code of move_imageto_dir() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your file inputs as a array

```
<input type="file" name="u_file[]" class="u_class" id="u_id">
```

`$_FILES['u_file']` is a array now

```
foreach ($_FILES['u_file'] as $file) {
$image_name=$file['name'];

move_imageto_dir();
etc....

}
```

Comment: good idea . I just forgot it . Could you please update your answer with foreach loop.

Comment: Noe u_file is array . When i am printing the array for some reason it is only taking the latest image .

Comment: what do you mean by latest, note you need the notation for all the file inputs

Comment: if first i select 1.jpg, then 2.peg,3.jpeg . Then form submit ant print $_FILES['u_file'] then it output is only showing this Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 3.jpeg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php1nrbbV ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 6733 ) )

Comment: can you provide the parsed html of your file upload form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127081/discussion-between-ron-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 1):

You can use array symbol with the name of file

```
<input type="file" name="u_file[]" class="u_class" id="u_id">
```

Now in php you can receive files like this

```
$_FILES['file']['u_file'][0]
$_FILES['file']['u_file'][1]
```

Or you can use `loop` also

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['u_file'] as $filename) {}
```